# My data is displaying incorrectly in VisualBasic by importing it from another document

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to grab data from another excel document. The main idea is simply to grab a cell data and put it in a cell in the new document.

For numbers different to 0 the display is correct; but when the cell data is 0 or any other simple String the new cell will display empty.
The only way it works is if you put the ' symbol in the original cell before the 0 or the String.

Do you know why this could happen ?

Here's an example

```
'Number in Scope (Aus Basisdata!D9 in Column I)
Scope.Cells(NextRow, Column).FormulaLocal = "='" & DateiPath & "]Basisdata'!$D$9"
        Column = Column + 1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should include the code, in which the import is done. It is quite difficult to debug code, without being able to see it.

Comment: Please let us know whether the "number format" for the cell that you are copying into is perhaps set to display blank for zeroes and text.  We may as well eliminate the obvious things to start with.

Comment: There I edited the document with the code inside

Comment: What happens if you type the formula into the cell manually?  Does it still display as blank?  (If it does, it isn't the code you posted that is causing the issue.)

Comment: Manually change the cell format to be "General" and see whether something is displayed.

Comment: @YowE3K Just did both of them and none shows anything

Comment: If you use Formulas / Evaluate Formula, does it correctly show the evaluation of the formula, or does it show blank there too?

Comment: yes, also empty

Comment: Are you sure that the referred-to cell has a 0 (or some text) in it?!?!  If you double-click the cell containing the formula, does it take you to the cell you are expecting it to be referring to?

Comment: I'm afraid I have to call it a night now - hopefully someone else will wander past the question and help you out further.

Comment: @YowE3K yes, in the exact moment I put a number different to 0 or add the ' symbol before the 0 it's shown in the document
Thanks anyways